# How can I make video calls on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, skype

I would like to know the easiest method of video calling from my new laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried Skype but it keeps crashing and also tried whatsApp, which does not provide a video call option for this version.

Comment: You could try [appear.in](https://appear.in/). It runs in a browser, so no need to install additional software.

Comment: You can try any of the following: [Talky](https://talky.io/), [Cisco Spark](https://web.ciscospark.com/), [Jitsi Meet](https://meet.jit.si/), and yes, [Appearin](https://appear.in/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try update and upgrade your system first, then install skypeforlinux from repository. Skype worked on 2 computers with no problem :).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can get skype from: https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/
Move to download folder and install .deb file

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Hope i helped :)